# No xtick and ytick showing matplotlib object oriented

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code performs a plot but no ticks on the x or y axis are showing and I don't understand why.

```
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ax.set_title("test plot")
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7,8])
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Why aren't they automatically added ?

I also copied some other example using the object oriented approach of matplotlib and I ran through the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your axes are actually "there" they are just at the limits of the figure. When you call [`add_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) the rectangle you give it is of the form `[left, bottom, width, height]`. You are giving it the point `(0, 0)` as the starting point (bottom left corner) and a width and height of 1 (so the full width and height of the figure). You can play around with the coordinates to see what happens e.g.

```py
ax = fig.add_axes([0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6])
```

gives

[image]

while

```py
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.4,0.4])
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I see thanks. Is there a simple way to make sure that thos relative positionning are done "including the ticks" ? Or we are forced to add some random number that match (like 0.1 here).

Comment: If you just want a figure and an axes I'd suggest doing `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` instead of `fig = plt.figure()` and `fig.add_axes()` as is typically done in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#a-simple-example). Use `add_axes` if you need finer control.